# Compare two tables and filter the results

Tags: sql, compare

I am trying to do a comparison between two tables, an then return orphan records. By this I mean compare CustomerA with CustomerB, exclude any matches, and return all unmatched records. I have the following:

```
CustomerA | CustomerB
```

In CustomerA Table I have the following columns:

```
|Name        | PostCode     |
```

In CustomerB Table, I have the following column:

```
| PostCode     |
```

I am trying to match CustomerA' Table Postcode column with CustomerB Tables, which I have done as follows:

```
select postcode from TestDB.dbo.customerA
except
select postcode from TestDB.dbo.customerB
```

However, I am only getting the Postcode as a returned results after the query above without the names:

```
| PostCode     | 
| A32 245      | 
| B44 345      | 
| C54 342      |
```

I need the names in there as well. For example:

```
|Name       | PostCode     | 
|James      | A32 245      | 
|Roger      | B44 345      | 
|Smith      | C54 342      |
```

At the same time, would it be possible to filter the returned results by name? For instance after a compare, can I further drill down and get all orphan records that have the name 'James'?

Just started out in SQL queries, so would appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want all the records from CustomerA where the post code is not matched in CustomerB. That could be done like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerA
WHERE PostCode NOT IN
  (SELECT PostCode FROM CustomerB);
```

To get just a particular customer:

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerA
WHERE PostCode NOT IN
  (SELECT PostCode FROM CustomerB)
AND Name = 'James';
```

Comment: NOT IN is a bit dangerous, you know the NULL thing people always tend to forget. My advice is to use NOT EXISTS instead (always).

Comment: Agreed. NOT EXISTS would be better here.

Comment: How do I implement the NOT Exists? Also I have over 30 million records per table, I have noticed that the when I run the above query, the execution time is gone over the 20 minute mark; where as what I tried executed in less than a minute. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have indexes on PostCode in both tables?

Comment: SELECT * FROM CustomerA ca WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PostCode FROM CustomerB cb WHERE cb.PostCode = ca.PostCode);

Answer (score 0):

You  should compare only what is called the primary key, an attribute which identifies each individual and is always unique. It can be the DNI for example. Yes, you can filter result with a SELECT query

```
Select * from table where user = 'name';
```

Comment: Alvaro, I know how to query for individual names, but I need the comparison to take place, then return the result with both Name & Postcode, then search for a user such as James.

Comment: I think you are looking for the SQL statement Join or inner join. You can combine tables by column/s or other parameters to make one combined table. I guess then you can do a select from that table to filter specific names